# How the state of Ethereum blockchain is updated?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum

How can I update the status of the blockchain?

1. I issue a transaction and pass an id to the smart contract. Smart contract A retrieves data from smart contract B and uses it to check whether a condition in the smart contract is true or not. If checked, save 'id, true' otherwise 'id, false.' My first question is: should there be a transaction to save this information on the blockchain? I only have the initial transaction sending id, so how is this possible?
2. I store id, true. After some time the value true becomes false. But if the old pair was stored on the blockchain and the blockchain is immutable, how can the copy be updated?

I am using Ethereum

Comment: the only way to change data on the blockchain is by sending transaction, because only by detecting your signature we know who is changing the state

Comment: the inmutable is only the binary code of the contract. the storage of the contract is mutable

Answer (score 2):

Though blockchain is immutable, it does not mean the current state can not be updated. Each Ethereum block is a new state that consists of account balances and smart contract variables. The current state is the last valid block which your Ethereum node sees. History cannot be altered, but the current state can be altered with transactions.

As the question is overly broad and over basic blockchain concepts, I suggest taking classes in Ethereum smart contract development first.

Comment: I am working on a project where a client wants to make a reservation in a city, but the reservation is accepted only if the weather conditions are good. The first step is to send a transaction to the smart contract with the customer id and other parameters such as the city where to make the reservation.
After collecting this data through an oracle, the smart contract compares the data, determines if a reservation is valid and saves 'id, true' or 'id, false'. My question is: where is this data ('id, true' or 'id, false') saved?

Comment: My second question is: periodically, the oracle sends updated weather data to the smart contract and if there are any changes I must be able to change 'id, true' -> 'id, false' to indicate that due to changes that reservation is not more valid. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @MarioRoma contracts have internal storage slots. The contract can write to them or read them using a key. It is a key-value trie. Every update to contract's storage is tracked via hashing the contract's storage trie, then this change is going to change all the hashes up the hierarchy until the hash of the entire Block. It is stored on all the 10k nodes of Ethereum network.